# Making Chrome App interact with Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Well my question is pretty much like [Proper way to listen as TCP server in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715457/proper-way-to-listen-as-tcp-server-in-chrome-extension)

But the problem is that the question above was not properly answered, and the questions persists.

So, is there a way to make a Chrome App interact with a Chrome extension. The purposes are much like the question referenced above, in resume It's for building a TCP Server and manage content in a tab web page.

Well as far as I know there's no way of doing that, because Chrome App does not have access to a web page content and a Chrome Extensions are not allowed to use sockets.

So any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite being called ["cross-extension messaging"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external), it works between extensions and apps.

Presumably, you'll want long-lived connections; then you can use:

```
// In one app/extension that initiates the connection
// (Probably the app upon a new client connecting)
var port = chrome.runtime.connect(secondID);

// In other app/extension
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    // See other examples for sample onMessage handlers.
  });
});
```

Remember that you want to make sure the connection comes from something you trust. While an imperfect defense, you should check the originator's extension/app ID - whether in your code or by filtering the rest out with `externally_connectable` manifest key (default is permissive).